# MYSQL ODBC adding server name to user name

Tags: mysql, odbc

Trying to create an ODBC connection from a server to MySQL server.  installed 5.1 ODBC driver on the server I want to connect from.  when I go to test the connection - the MySql server denies access to user -- then it lists the username with a `"@servername.domain.com"` appended to it.  why is the ODBC appeneding that?   so clearly we are connecting to the MySQL server.  Both serers are in the same domain behind the firewall.  is there somethign on the MySQL server need to configure?

Comment: That's how MySQL users work. They're bind to either a specific host name or wildcard `%` to mean "any host".

Comment: I read a comment from a person that had the same issue where he created a user on his MySQL instance that included the @server.domain.com and the ODBC conenction still appened the info again.   I have not tested that - just looking at what needs to be done.  how do I set up the user properly on MySQL?

Comment: Just make sure you have either `foo@servername.domain.com` or `foo@%` in your user list and they have the appropriate privileges. Connecting via ODBC doesn't make it different.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am having the same issue, and my website isn't allowing me to enter a username with special characters ("@").